# quotation marks elimination from shift array

Tags: python

I have a question. I have this array but I don't know how to eliminate single quotation marks. I have this, can you help me with it?

```
array([['0.3', '0.3', '0.3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['1.0', '1.0', '1.0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0.7', '0.7', '0.7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0.3', '0.3', '0.3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0.7', '0.7', '0.7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0.3', '0.3', '0.3', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0.3', '0.3', '0.3', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0.3', '0.3', '0.3', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.7', '0.7', '0.7', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.3', '0.3', '0.3', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.3', '0.3', '0.3', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.3', '0.3', '0.3'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']],
      dtype=object)
```

I tried this :

```
dfff1 = dfff.replace("'", " ") but I got this error:
```

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'

Should I use "for" to gedd rid of it? something like: for mar1 in dfff:

```
 for mar2 in mar1:
        mar2.replace("''", "")
```

the problem with this is that I don't know how to make them an array again ( with the same order)

Comment: The quotation marks aren't in your data.  They're delimiters which indicate that your values are strings.  To convert them to floating point values, use `float`, e.g. `float('1.0')` evaluates to the floating point number `1.0`.

Comment: Try `dfff.astype(float)`